How to parse HTML hidden behind JS scripts
The FCC has a database with details about various broadcast licenses. Many of these licenses have pages like this one
Most of the data on these pages (and related ones) can be scraped very easily with a combination of the standard requests library and BeautifulSoup4. You just scrape the HTML, target the data you want, and you're good to go.
I took the same approach to extracting this Spectrum and Market Area table (pictured below), but have run into a roadblock.
Table I want to extract from the page
Though the individual table rows can be inspected with browser dev tools, when I scrape the HTML with something like this:
import requests

url = "https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/leasesList.jsp?licKey=2591153"
output_file = "license_page_leases.html"
response = requests.get(url)
    
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(response.text)

... no part of the table itself is downloaded - all I get is the javascript that appears to generate the table.
So my question: how do I scrape the data in this kind of table?
I've tried various similar ways of scraping this table.
I've also tried to see if theres some underlying query structure available that would let me make a request more directly to their DB, to no success.
If there's an obvious solution I'm missing, I'd love to know, but I don't necessarily need anyone to solve this problem for me - I'm here because I need advice on how to research this structure. I don't know what to call it when the html is generated on the fly like this, so its hard to research methods to grab it.
Thanks!

"all I get is the javascript that appears to generate the table" - It's not entirely clear to me what specifically you mean by that.  However, if the general problem is that you need JavaScript code to execute on the target page then you're probably looking for tools like Selenium, which act as a "headless browser", to include executing JavaScript and updating the DOM accordingly as one would observe in a standard web browser.  You could then query the resulting DOM, rather than only the raw initial HTML.

Try creating an XMLSerializer and feed it somethimg like document.body

You'd use your browser's Network inspector to see that that page makes a request to https://apps2.fcc.gov/geo-service/licensePartitionService/licenseAreas/2591153.jsonp?jsonpCallback=getAreas&_=1733254093937 and then parse that instead.

@AKX embarrassed I didn't think to check that before posting. Thanks for your help - this is exactly what I needed.

I have no doubt that a selenium-based approach has merit, but @AKX's suggestion in the comments to pull the .jsonb file from the Network inspector was the simplest solution.
I hadn't thought to do this, as this is non-standard behaviour for the webtool, from what I have seen so far.
Doing this let me have access to a a bunch of json data wrapped in eval(), i.e eval({...}). Trivial from there.

Try using selenium webdriver, it will execute the JS scripts, and you can hide or unhide the navigator
Here are the tutorial of how to use
You'll need to install Selenium pip install selenium and download the webdriver [instructions here]
